# Connect to EC2 instance with PuTTY, server refuses key

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, putty

I have started an EC2 instance that I cannot connect to using PuTTY. I'm using a key pair that I created using PuTTYgen and then imported to AWS. I have specified the private key file on the client side in Connection -> SSH -> Auth. I have SSH on port 22 selected for PuTTY. The EC2 instance has a single security group, and this group has an inbound rule allowing TCP on port 22 from my home laptop's IP address. Still no joy when I try to connect.

In the PuTTY window I see this:

```
Using username "ec2-user".
Server refused our key
```

Also an error dialogue box pops up with this message:

```
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey)
```

What other things should I look into or do differently? I have been successful with this before so I know that it can work, but apparently I've forgotten one or more pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: does it work directly from the AWS console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which Linux distribution are you using? ec2-user is only valid for Amazon Linux. If you use another Linux distribution user is root or ubuntu (for Ubuntu Linux).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information, very helpful. I'm using AMI == python-scientific-computing (ami-36d2865e). I will look into how you create users for an EC2 instance, create a new user and then login as that user, hopefully that will get me over the hump.

Comment: This was indeed the issue, I login as user 'ubuntu' and all is well now. Thanks big time for your help!

Answer (score 3):

For any future searchers having this problem, I found one more issue. I downloaded the .pem key from AWS and converted to .ppk and tried to ssh using Putty, and I would get 'Server refused key'. After much hair pulling I randomly updated Putty to the latest available version (0.77 as of writing) and that solved my issue. Same issue with WinSCP.

Comment: Thank you, I was using version 0.74 and having the same problem. Version 0.78 connected successfully!